# Company of Heroes and Company of Heroes tales of valor

Tags: steam, company-of-heroes

I Downloaded COH Tales of valor and after play i see need coh new steam version 
but when i click play it's want to download it 
but both files is same 
coh is 7.5 gb and coh tales of valor is 7.6gb 
and how i can get steam to validate coh tales of valor files to coh new steam version without download

Comment: Tales of Valour is a standalone game so the file size will be the same. All content on the non Steam versions is unlock able with a cd key so all versions need to contain all content. The Steam version will give you all of the content and access to multiplayer via steam works.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading TOV will bring in all the original COH content I believe. 
Just make sure its the "new steam version" so it uses the newer multiplayer servers.